# How to convert a DStream to avro form and save file in hdfs

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, avro

I have a DStream which is type [String , ArrayList[String]] , and I want to convert this DStream to avro format and save that to hdfs. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your stream to JavaRDD or convert it to DataFrame and write it to a file and provide format as Avro.

```
// Apply a schema to an RDD
DataFrame booksDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(books, Books.class);
booksDF.write()
    .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
    .save("/output");
```

Please visit [Accessing Avro Data Files From Spark SQL](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-7-x/topics/spark_avro.html#concept_hsz_nvn_45__section_u2b_kn5_st)  for more examples.

Hoping this helps.

Comment: DataFrame booksDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(books, Books.class);   Here is showing nullpointerException , in field for been class I am providing dstream.getClass() , and now I have converted my dstream og Type [GenericData.Record] so it would be helpful if you can answer in that context